# return user id django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model field

```
account_handler = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='handling_leads', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user_id = User.objects.all()
    queryset = User.objects.filter(handling_leads__account_handler=user_id).distinct()
    return queryset
```

and I've got some results for testing purposes. Now the question is, how can I properly use this field and return a `user_id`? I have tried something like this

```
User.objects.filter(handling_leads__account_handler=self.request.user.id).distinct()
```

with out `User.objects.all()` but that was just returning an empty queryset. I'm trying to filter this so I can populate a table with `user__first_name` and `user__last_name`, I need `user_id` so I can redirect them to their individual page.

controler for the datatable:

```
app = angular.module 'statistics'

app.controller 'SalesCommissionsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile',
  ($scope, $compile) ->
    $scope.init = ()->
      fetchCommissionsList()

    fetchCommissionsList = ()->
      $('#commissionsSalesList').DataTable({
        createdRow: (row, data, index) ->
          $compile(row)($scope)
        sDom: 'lftip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide:true,
        searchDelay: 1000,
        orderMulti: false,
        pageLength: 10,
        ajax: {
          url: '/api/statistics/commissions/list/',
          data: (data)->
            data.limit = data.length;
            data.offset = data.start;
            data.search = data.search['value'];
            if (data.order[0]['dir'] == 'asc')
              data.ordering = data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name;
            else
              data.ordering = '-' + data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name;
            return 0
          dataFilter: (data) ->
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            json.recordsTotal = json.count;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.count;
            json.data = json.results;
            return JSON.stringify(json);
        }
        columns: [
          {
            data: "username",
            name: "username__first_name, username__last_name",
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              return '<a href="/statistics/commissions/sales/' + row.user_id + '">' + data + '</a>';
          }
        ]
      })
]
```

my `ModelViewSet`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters, permissions

from app.restapi.pagination import StandardResultsOffsetPagination
from statistics.restapi.serializers import SalesCommissionsSerializer
from statistics.restapi.permissions import SalesCommissionsListPermissions


class SalesCommissionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = User.objects.all()
        queryset = User.objects.filter(handling_leads__account_handler=user_id).distinct()
        return queryset

    serializer_class = SalesCommissionsSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)

    filter_fields = (
        'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name'
    )

    ordering_fields = (
        'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
    )

    search_fields = (
        'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
    )

    pagination_class = StandardResultsOffsetPagination

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, SalesCommissionsListPermissions]
```

serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class SalesCommissionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Comment: I don't really understand this line: `user_id = User.objects.all()`. `user_id` implies **one** user, but you assign all Users to it.

Comment: @creimers I've made a little edit to the question so you can understand that that line was for testing purposes so I can populate my table with some kind a data, the question still remains

Comment: I still think your whole `get_queryset` method does not make much sense. What are you after, a single user?

Comment: @creimers all off them, so I can populate my table, the point is that I need user who are `handling_leads`, I need to put them into table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter for users who are 'handling leads', you can do the following:

`handling_leads = User.objects.filter(handling_leads__isnull=False)`

Here's a link to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull

Comment: Finally, thank you, was working for two hours on this